# How to remove multiple rows of the same person id in csv file

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df = pd.read_csv('time_var.txt', header = None, delimiter =r"\s+" )
df.columns = ["Id", "Edu", "Ln(w)", "PoEp","Ttd"]
```

I have a csv file like this:

[image]

This is the data set. Each person has multiple entries. I want to take only the first entry for each person.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Id', keep='first')
```